# How do you set up IIS 7.0 URL Rewrites without IIS Manager?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, shared-hosting

Does anyone know how to write your own specifications for the built-in URL Rewrite Module in IIS 7.0?

We are using a shared host that does not allow use of IIS 7.0 Remote Manager on shared accounts, but we'd like to employ URL rewriting for SEO purposes. All of the literature I can find relates to the URL Rewrite Module setup requiring IIS Manager.

I'm sure it's just a few settings in a web.config, but I've been testing blindly without much instruction to follow and nothing is working, thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL Rewriting module is not installed on the server you won't be able to enable it without admin's assistance. But you may have a look at an [alternative solution](http://helicontech.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-install-helicon-ape-on-shared.html).